# How to fix TensorFlow Linear Regression no change in MSE?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, training-data

I'm working on a simple linear regression model to predict the next step in a series. I'm giving it x/y coordinate data and I want the regressor to predict where the next point on the plot will lie.

I'm using dense layers with AdamOptmizer and have my loss function set to:

`tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(layer_out - y))`

I'm trying to create linear regression models from scratch (I don't want to utilize the TF estimator package here).

I've seen ways to do it by manually specifying weights and biases, but nothing goes into deep regression.

```
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.data_class.batch_size, self.inputs])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.data_class.batch_size, self.outputs])
    layer_input = tf.layers.dense(inputs=X, units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer_hidden = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_input, units=10, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer_out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_hidden, units=1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(layer_out - y))
    optmizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate)
    training_op = optmizer.minimize(cost)

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    iterations = 10000
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init.run()
        for iteration in range(iterations):
            X_batch, y_batch = self.data_class.get_data_batch()
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
            if iteration % 100 == 0:
                mse = cost.eval(feed_dict={X:X_batch, y:y_batch})
                print(mse)
        array = []
        for i in range(len(self.data_class.dates), (len(self.data_class.dates)+self.data_class.batch_size)):
            array.append(i)
        x_pred = np.array(array).reshape(1, self.data_class.batch_size, 1)
        y_pred = sess.run(layer_out, feed_dict={X: x_pred})
        print(y_pred)
        predicted = np.array(y_pred).reshape(self.data_class.batch_size)
        predicted = np.insert(predicted, 0, self.data_class.prices[0], axis=0)
        plt.plot(self.data_class.dates, self.data_class.prices)
        array = [self.data_class.dates[0]]
        for i in range(len(self.data_class.dates), (len(self.data_class.dates)+self.data_class.batch_size)):
            array.append(i)

        plt.plot(array, predicted)
        plt.show()
```

When I run training I'm getting the same loss value over and over again.

It's not being reduced, like it should, why?

Comment: What is the data? What is the evaluation result? What have you achieved so far? It is not clear what is the problem.

Comment: The data is just X/Y coordinate data. 

The evaluation is just returning the same loss as MSE and the same number over and over again. Basically I'm giving it an X value and trying to get it to predict the corresponding Y value.

Comment: Could it be the architecture of the model?

Comment: Are you sure you feed the right data format in the model? The placeholder shape is (none, batch_size, input).

Comment: Yeah my batching method is as follows:
```
 def get_data_batch(self):
  start = (self.current_batch * self.batch_size)
  end = (self.current_batch+1) * self.batch_size
  return np.array(self.x[start: end]).reshape(1, self.batch_size, 1), np.array(self.y[start: end]).reshape(1, self.batch_size, 1)```



I'm making sure to reshape the data as needed.

Comment: Is it possible that there is just no convergence within the data?

That seems to make the most sense here...

Comment: Or could it be my output layer?

Comment: It was my output! I just got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I'm applying an activation to the output layer. This is causing that output to go to whatever it activates to.

By specifying in the last layer that activation=None the deep regression works as intended.

Here is the updated architecture:

```
layer_input = tf.layers.dense(inputs=X, units=150, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer_hidden = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_input, units=100, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    layer_out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer_hidden, units=1, activation=None)
```